# How can I write a function that counts a number of elements in the list that are strictly greater and strictly lower than the given number?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to learn Haskell through [this course](https://github.com/haskell-beginners-2022/course-plan), and I'm a bit stuck with the last assignment in the first module. The problem statement sounds as follows:

> Write a function that takes a number and a list of numbers and
> returns a string, saying how many elements of the list are strictly
> greater than the given number and strictly lower.
>
> ```
> lowerAndGreater 3 [1 .. 9]
> "3 is greater than 2 elements and lower than 6 elements"
> ```
>
> Explanation: the list [1 .. 9] contains 9 elements: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
> The given number 3 is greater than 2 elements (1 and 2)
> and lower than 6 elements (4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9).
>
> HINT: Use recursion to implement this function.

Here is my attempt  to solve the problem:

```
lowerAndGreater :: Int -> [Int] -> String
lowerAndGreater n list = show(n) ++ " is greater than " ++ show(lesserThanN n list) ++ " elements and lower than " ++ show(greaterThanN n list) ++ " elements"
    where
        greaterThanN :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
        greaterThanN greater l =
            if null l
            then greater
            else if head l > n
                 then greaterThanN (greater + 1) (tail l)
                 else greaterThanN greater       (tail l)

        lesserThanN :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
        lesserThanN lesser l =
            if null l
            then lesser
            else if head l < n
                 then lesserThanN (lesser + 1) (tail l)
                 else lesserThanN lesser       (tail l)
```

Unfortunately, the execution results aren't what I expect, e.g.

```
lowerAndGreater 3 [1 .. 9]
"3 is greater than 5 elements and lower than 9 elements"
```

Could you please advice where my mistake is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be better to enumerate over the list a single time. We can do this with a function that returns a 2-tuple with:

```
import Control.Arrow (first, second)

lowerAndGreater :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> (Int, Int)
lowerAndGreater y = foldr go (0, 0)
  where
    go x
        | x < y = first (+ 1)
        | x > y = second (+ 1)
        | otherwise = id
```

This then gives us:

```
ghci> lowerAndGreater 3 [1 .. 9]
(2,6)
```

Comment: Wow, that's very elegant solution, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Just managed to find the solution - I shouldn't pass "n" as a parameter to the lesserThanN and greaterThanN functions. Instead of that, I should just pass 0.

The correct code is

```
lowerAndGreater :: Int -> [Int] -> String
lowerAndGreater n list = show(n) ++ " is greater than " ++ show(lesserThanN 0 list) ++ " elements and lower than " ++ show(greaterThanN 0 list) ++ " elements"
    where
        greaterThanN :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
        greaterThanN greater l =
            if null l
            then greater
            else if head l > n
                 then greaterThanN (greater + 1) (tail l)
                 else greaterThanN greater       (tail l)

        lesserThanN :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
        lesserThanN lesser l =
            if null l
            then lesser
            else if head l < n
                 then lesserThanN (lesser + 1) (tail l)
                 else lesserThanN lesser       (tail l)
```

Comment: Your code now works. As a general recommendation, usually it's better to avoid to use `null, head, tail` to access lists, since if one forgets the `null` check and calls `head` or `tail`, that will cause the whole program to crash. As a simple safe alternative is to use exhaustive pattern matching: using two equations we have `lesserThanN lesser [] = lesser` and `lesserThanN lesser (x:xs) = if x < n then lesserThanN (lesser+1) xs else lesserThanN lesser xs`.

Comment: (Well, there's also the option to use `filter` and/or a list comprehension, but I guess you wanted to use explicit recursion as an exercise).

Comment: Noted with thanks! I'm using head/tail as both methods are covered during the lecture and my knowledge is limited for now. The lecturer has highlighted the same concern as you about the null.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers are nice because they are very beginner-friendly, using only concepts and functions from early in a Haskell curriculum. I thought it might be interesting to show an example of what an advanced solution might look like; this isn't obviously better (or worse) to me, but this is the kind of tool I would reach for when doing this kind of thing. The [multiset](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-0.3.4.3/docs/Data-MultiSet.html) package provides a way to count elements of a list, which we can directly reuse; along the way, we'll get for free a count of how many elements were *equal* to the number as well.

```
import qualified Data.MultiSet as MS

comparisons :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> MS.MultiSet Ordering
comparisons a = MS.fromList . map (compare a)
```

Try it out:

```
> comparisons 3 [1..9]
fromOccurList [(LT,6),(EQ,1),(GT,2)]
```

You can retrieve the answers you care about using `occur`; for example,

```
> let cs = comparisons 3 [1..9] in (MS.occur GT cs, MS.occur LT cs)
(2, 6)
```